# Why is my semaphore lock not locking this process as expected? (Multithreading)

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, posix, semaphore

I'm currently writing a program that takes an array that has randomly generated numbers, and uses multithreading to essentially divide the array in equal parts, then each thread will find the minimum of their respective division of the array. Essentially, I need my parent thread to be blocked (have non-busy waiting for parallel processing efficiency) using semaphores while the child threads are looking for the minimum, however the combination of sem_wait and sem_post is not blocking the parent thread as expected.

I've attempted to change the sem_init parameters to different values, however it seems no matter what I do the parent doesn't actually get blocked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100000000
#define MAX_THREADS 16
#define RANDOM_SEED 8631
#define MAX_RANDOM_NUMBER 5000

// Global variables
long gRefTime; //For timing
int gData[MAX_SIZE]; //The array that will hold the data

int gThreadCount; //Number of threads
int gDoneThreadCount; //Number of threads that are done at a certain point. Whenever a thread is done, it increments this. Used with the semaphore-based solution
int gThreadMin[MAX_THREADS]; //The minimum value found by each thread
bool gThreadDone[MAX_THREADS]; //Is this thread done? Used when the parent is continually checking on child threads
int indices[MAX_THREADS][3];

// Semaphores
sem_t completed; //To notify parent that all threads have completed or one of them found a zero
sem_t mutex; //Binary semaphore to protect the shared variable gDoneThreadCount
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    pthread_t tid[MAX_THREADS];  
    pthread_attr_t attr[MAX_THREADS];

    int i, indexForZero, arraySize, min;

    // Code for parsing and checking command-line arguments
    if(argc != 4){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of arguments!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if((arraySize = atoi(argv[1])) <= 0 || arraySize > MAX_SIZE){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Array Size\n");
        exit(-1);               
    }
    gThreadCount = atoi(argv[2]);               
    if(gThreadCount > MAX_THREADS || gThreadCount <=0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Thread Count\n");
        exit(-1);               
    }
    indexForZero = atoi(argv[3]);
    if(indexForZero < -1 || indexForZero >= arraySize){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid index for zero!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    GenerateInput(arraySize, indexForZero);

    CalculateIndices(arraySize, gThreadCount, indices); 


InitSharedVars();
SetTime();


// Initialize threads, create threads, and then make the parent wait on the "completed" semaphore 
// The thread start function is ThFindMinWithSemaphore

sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
sem_init(&completed, 0, 0);

for(i=0; i < gThreadCount; i++){
pthread_attr_init(&attr[i]);
        pthread_create(&tid[i],&attr[i],ThFindMinWithSemaphore,&indices[i]);
}

sem_wait(&completed);

if(gThreadDone[i] == true && gThreadMin[i] == min){ 
     for(i=0; i < gThreadCount; i++){
    pthread_cancel(tid[i]);
    }
}


min = SearchThreadMin();
printf("Threaded FindMin with parent waiting on a semaphore completed in %ld ms. Min = %d\n", GetTime(), min);
void* ThFindMinWithSemaphore(void *param) {
    int threadNum = ((int*)param)[0];

    int i;
    int startIndex = indices[threadNum][1];
    int endIndex = indices[threadNum][2];
    sem_wait(&completed);

    for (i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {   
        if (gData[i] < gThreadMin[threadNum]){
            gThreadMin[threadNum] = gData[i];
        }
        else if (gData[i] == 0){
            sem_post(&completed);
            pthread_exit(0);
        }
}

    sem_wait(&mutex);
    gDoneThreadCount++;
    sem_post(&mutex);

    if (gDoneThreadCount == gThreadCount){
    sem_post(&completed);
    }
pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Note that this is not all of the file code that is actually in the file.

I want the main function to wait at the line where it says sem_wait(&completed). The goal is to have the child threads signal the parent by using sem_post when each thread is done searching for their minimum value, or one of the threads has found a zero within the array. Then at that point the main function should continue after receiving that sem_post signal.

As I understand, if the semaphore completed has a count of zero which I have initialized it to that using sem_init(&completed, 0, 0), the caller for sem_wait waits until it receives sem_post from one of the child threads. It appears that my program does not do the wait as expected.

Comment: This is not the answer but... Mutex is not semaphore. You should use pthread_mutex for mutex.

Comment: Can you tell what is the behavior you are observing? For me it looks like a deadlock as "completed" has intial value "0" and you are doing "sem_wait(&completed);" in both main() and ThFindMinWithSemaphore(). So "sem_wait(&completed);" in ThFindMinWithSemaphore() should be removed.